# Sort data within one output directory created by partitionBy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sorting, partitioning

I have a big geospatial dataset partitionBy quadkey's level 5.
In each qk5 level directory, there are about 1-50 Gb of data, so it doesn't fit into one file. I want to benefit from pushdown filters when do my geospatial queries. So I want that files within one qk5 partition be sorted by higher qk resolution (let's say quadkey level 10).
Question: Is there are a way to sort data within partitionBy batch?
For example:

```
qk5=00001/
    part1.parquet
    part2.parquet
    part3.parquet
    part4.parquet
...

qk5=33333/
    part10000.parquet
    part20000.parquet
    part30000.parquet
    part40000.parquet
```

I want to have data from part1.parquet, part2.parquet, part3.parquet, part4.parquet to be sorted by column 'qk10'.

Here is the current code, but it only provides sorting within one particular partition (e.g. part1.parquet):

```
// Parquet save
preExportRdd.toDF
  .repartition(partitionsNumber, $"salt")
  .sortWithinPartitions($"qk10")
  .drop("salt")
  .write
  .partitionBy("qk")
  .format("parquet")
  .option("compression", "gzip")
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .save(exportUrl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't sort your Dataframe globally by `qk` field and it causes for the same `qk` values to be distributed in different spark partitions.
During the write phase, due to `partitionBy("qk")`, the output written to a specific physical partition (folder) may arrive from different spark partitions, which causes your output data to be unsorted.

Try instead the following:

```
preExportRdd.toDF
  .repartitionByRange(partitionsNumber, $"qk", $"qk10", $"salt")
  .sortWithinPartitions($"qk10")
  .drop("salt")
  .write
  .partitionBy("qk")
  .format("parquet")
  .option("compression", "gzip")
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .save(exportUrl)
```

The `repartitionByRange` will sort your Dataframe by the provided columns and split the sorted Dataframe to the desired number of partitions.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do I need a salting technique in case of repartitionByRange? As far as I understood it should chunk partitions by similar sizes?

Comment: repartitionByRange will partition the data based on a range of the column values, which is calculated by a sampling proccess in order to estimate those ranges. Therefore, if `qk` and `qk10` are not well distributed, a salting technique might be helpful (otherwise, the repartitionByRange might yield less partitions than partitionsNumber)

Comment: thanks. 
I am wondering if repartitionByRange requires more memory on the driver than repartition action. I've changed the last one to repartitionByRange and it is started failing on cluster with OOM